# Can the Limited Wish spell be used to cast spells from prohibited schools of magic?

Tags: spells, dnd-3.5e, wish

I'm playing a silverbrow human sorcerer in D&D 3.5e and a prestige class I plan on taking in the future requires me to select a school of magic to prohibit. I'm having trouble deciding which school to choose, so I'm wondering if *limited wish* would allow me to duplicate the effect of a spell from the prohibited school.

Comment: Also, Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already and see the [help] or ask us here in the comments (use @ to ping someone) if you need more guidance. Good Luck and Happy Gaming!

Comment: Which prestige class? All of the ones that I can think of that require you to ban a school strike me as very odd choices for a Sorcerer.

Comment: @J.Mini Incantatrix is the most notable one that comes to mind.

Comment: @JohnMontgomery I strongly agree, Incantrix for a sorcerer that follows the ''mailman build'' makes a very powerful build, finally a class that is even better than the wizard if it is optimized.

Answer (score 14):

#### Limited wish can duplicate up to a 5th-level spell that's from one of a caster's prohibited schools

The 7th-level Sor/Wiz spell [***limited wish***](http://dndsrd.net/spellsHtoL.html#limited-wish) [univ] (*Player's Handbook* 248), in part, says that its effect can "[d]uplicate any sorcerer/wizard spell of 5th level or lower, even if it’s of a prohibited school."

Answer (score 8):

## Yes but only up to spells of 5th level for Wizard/Sorcerer spells

*Limited wish* states:

> A limited wish lets you create nearly any type of effect. For example, a limited wish can do any of the following things.
>
> - Duplicate any **sorcerer/wizard spell** of 6th level or lower, provided    the spell is **not of a school prohibited to you**.
> - Duplicate **any other spell** of 5th level or lower, provided the spell    **is not of a school prohibited to you**.
> - Duplicate any **sorcerer/wizard** spell of 5th level or lower, **even if    it's of a prohibited school.**
> - Duplicate **any other spell** of 4th level or lower, **even if it's of a    prohibited school.**
> - (...)

### SideNotes:

- You could ban Conjuration or evocation  (but shades only mimics conjuration) (but banning enchantment would
  probably be better) and use the spells *Shades*, *greater Shadow
  Conjuration* or *Shadow Conjuration* Wich could be useful since a
  single spell (or 2 or 3) can mimick all of one school (summoning or creation for conjuration) (up to level
  8th spells) wich could be really useful for a sorcerer and has [no exp/material cost](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/165880/51979) (*limited wish* costs 300xp or more!) it is an illusion.
- If you can have access to a *Collar of Umbral Metamorphosis (continuous)* (*Tome of magic* p.156) (wich gives you the [Dark Creature template](https://www.realmshelps.net/monsters/templates/dark.shtml) (*Tome of magic* p.161) and changes your Environment to the planes of shadow (native plan) **However the price should be way higher for this item**)
  and combine it with the spell *[Planar Bubble](https://dndtools.net/spells/spell-compendium--86/planar-bubble--4633/)* here's what happens:
- > **Enhanced magic**. Spells with the shadow descriptor are enhanced on the
  >   Plane of Shadow. **Such spells are cast as though they were prepared
  >   with the Maximize Spell feat, though they don’t require the higher
  >   spell slots**. Furthermore, specific spells become more powerful on the
  >   Plane of Shadow. **Shadow conjuration and shadow evocation spells are
  >   30% as powerful as the conjurations and evocations they mimic (as
  >   opposed to 20%). Greater shadow conjuration and greater shadow
  >   evocation are 70% as powerful (not 60%), and a shades spell conjures
  >   at 90% of the power of the original (not 80%)**.
- > **Impeded magic**. Spells
  >   that use or generate light or fire may fizzle when cast on the Plane
  >   of Shadow. A spellcaster attempting a spell with the light or fire
  >   descriptor must succeed on a Spellcraft check (DC 20 + the level of
  >   the spell). Spells that produce light are less effective in general,
  >   because all light sources have their ranges halved on the Plane of
  >   Shadow. Despite the dark nature of the Plane of Shadow, spells that
  >   produce, use, or manipulate darkness are unaffected by the plane.
- The *Spell Planar* bubble even confirms it would give you all the
  benefits/drawbacks I mentionned:

  > (...)This spell cast on a native of the Plane of    Shadow would make the
  >   area around her have normal gravity, a mild    neutral alignment,
  >   **enhanced shadow spells, and impeded light spells**.

  (A mildly neutral-aligned plane does not apply a circumstance penalty to anyone. [SRD](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/planes.htm))

Comment: Addes Sidenotes and:Waiting for confirmation on my claim: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/165871/51979