# Does Shades/Shadow Conjuration/Evocation requires material components?

Tags: spells, dnd-3.5e, spell-components, illusion

I'm pretty sure the answer is no, but I just wanted to be sure I didn't miss a rule somewhere, after all it is an illusion.

Let's say I use *Shadow Conjuration, Greater* to duplicate *Acid Storm* that normally requires A flask of acid (10 gp) since *Shadow Conjuration* states:

> You use material from the Plane of Shadow

The Material components are not necessary Am-I right? If there's such a spell that would require  a focus/exp component is it ok to apply the same logic as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes - the answer is **NO**.

I can´t see a rule that you could have missed. There is no mentioning of any material component you need.

Comment: Maybe, things like Magic Jar are worth mentioning? Will it work without a focus gem?

Comment: @annoying imp Magic Jar is a necromancy spell. So it cannot be mimicked by Shadow Conjuration or Shadow Evocation ...

Comment: @annoying imp if you can find other examples like this for Conjuration/Abjuration spells I'd be interested.

Comment: @MaximeCuillerier I'd start with Contingency, but I'll check if I can find more Conj/Evoc spells where material components/focus are clearly intended to be the part  of functioning spell, not just an extra fee to cast it.

Comment: I think Contingency is not eligible for shadow evocation (Greater) because it will emulate Contingency, but Contingency does nothing on it's own it needs to have a companion spell, and a spell like ''contingency:Celerity is not an existent spell''.

Comment: I'll ask it here directly. https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/165947/51979

Comment: @annoyingimp it interests me but since it is an illusion it clearly does not need such components. It would had been added in the spell description IMO (but if you find some info in FAQ or something I'll gladly welcome it)

Comment: @annoyingimp oh and by the way if you indeed need an object to use the spell on it does state: Objects automatically succeed on their Will saves against this spell.

Comment: @MaximeCuillerier I actually didn't meant what you ask in a followup question. I reffered "You must carry the focus for the contingency to work." So even if you can **cast** Contingency without focus component, will or will not it **work** without it?